# [jquery validation plugin]How to prevent the "alert()" when the selectbox is clicked?

Tags: jquery, validation, select

I am using jquery(latest[1.7.1]) validtion(latest[1.9.0]) plugin to validate my form,and I only need to use the alert() function to show the error message.Please see my sorce code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test_validation</title>
<style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0;}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" action="" style="text-align:center;">
        <select name="select"><option value=""></option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" /><input type="button" value="cancel" name="cancel" />
    </form>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#form1").validate({
            rules:{
                "select":"required"
            },
            messages:{
                "select":"required"
            },
            onkeyup:false,
            //showErrors:function(errorMap,errorList) {
//              if(errorList[0]){
//                  alert(errorList[0].message);
//              }
//              
//          },
            errorPlacement:function(error,element){
                alert(error.text());
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying two ways("showErrors" or "errorPlacement") to overide the default display,and,when I click the submit button,the message alerted,it's ok.Then,when I click the select box to choose a valid value,the message alerted again!I can not choose a value in fact,what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

add `onclick: false` to the options. This will disable onclick validation of buttons.

Comment: This will also disable checkboxes and radio buttons,right?Is there other way to only apply the selectbox?

Comment: exactly, but as far as I'm concerned, checking the form on submitting should be sufficient.